# Forge viewer Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT not being triggered for pdf files

Tags: javascript, autodesk, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

In my code I've attached listeners to the `Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT` event to ensure things are only run after the viewer is completely done with loading the model file. I've followed examples from [this](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/08/asynchronous-viewer-events-notification.html).

```
// Attach event handlers
viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT, () => $timeout(handleViewerGeometryLoaded));         
viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, () => $timeout(handleViewerSelectionChanged));


function handleViewerGeometryLoaded() {
   // Perform some actions here after everything is loaded.
}
```

And this is works completely fine as long as the `GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT` get's triggered when the viewer is done loading the file. But one thing I've found recently that for some file types like `pdf` this event wont' get triggered. For all the other files like 3d files, rvt, dwg files etc this works perfectly fine. But in case of pdf files this is not working.

Is this correct that this won't work for pdf files? What can I do to know when these files are loaded by the viewer then? Is there any other similar events that I can use here?

In our application we need to support all kinds of files from 3d models to 2d files including even pdf files. So, I need some kind of event that get's triggered when the loading is done for all file types supported by the viewer.

Thanks.

Comment: .pdf do not contain any geometry, so I guess it is expected that GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT doesn't fire. I'm checking with the development team if there is another event that you can use to make sure the document is fully loaded

Comment: @PhilippeLeefsma Okay, that make sense. But I do need some event to listen to, to know when the viewer has completely loaded the file. Let me know if there are any kind of workaround for this.

Comment: That's precisely what I'm asking for, I'll let you know as I get a feedback ...

Comment: You could try the "PROGRESS_UPDATE_EVENT" which is fired with a progress value that indicates the amount of data streamed so far. This is used by the viewer progress bar (lower left)

Comment: Okay, will try that. Thanks :)

Comment: Okay, it seems like the `PROGRESS_UPDATE_EVENT` gets triggered. But it's triggered multiple times even after the progress is 100 percent already. Like it will be triggered even if you zoom in & out in the model viewer. Anyway, I had a workaround to make it work. Thanks.

Comment: @PhilippeLeefsma BTW, is it possible to know if the type of model is `pdf` or if it doesn`t contain any geometry?

Comment: I'm not sure but you can always base64 decode the URN, which will tell you what is the file extension you are loading ...

Comment: Okay, will try that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, I tried everything but eventually I had to do this hack to make it work in my application. But it did the job :)

```
let modelCompletelyLoaded === false;

function ensureModelsWithoutGeometryLoaded(viewer) {
    const CHECK_INTERVAL = 1000;

    return new Promise(resolve => {
        // This is a dirty hack we need to do to ensure pdf files
        // to know when pdf files are loaded. We had to do this since
        // the GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT won't get triggered for the pdf files and
        // the files that doesn't have any geometry so we need to poll continously
        // to know if the model is fully loaded.
        let loadChecker = setInterval(() => {
            let hasMyData = viewer.model && viewer.model.myData;
            let loaded = hasMyData && viewer.model.myData.loadDone;
            let is2d = hasMyData && viewer.model.myData.is2d;
            let hasInstanceTree = hasMyData && (typeof viewer.model.myData.instanceTree === 'object');

            // It's not a 2d model, or the instanceTree has been loaded i.e the it has geometry
            // it implies that this couldn't be a pdf file, just skip it.
            if (is2d === false || hasInstanceTree) {
                clearInterval(loadChecker);
            } else if (loaded) {
                // Loaded now. Okay, great trigger the event finally.
                resolve();
                clearInterval(loadChecker);
            }
        }, CHECK_INTERVAL);
    });
}

function handleObjectLoaded() {
    if (modelCompletelyLoaded === true) {
        return
    }

    modelCompletelyLoaded === true;

    // Perform some actions here after everything is loaded.
    // ...
}

// Attach event handlers (this would work for all the files except those that doesn't have geometry data).
viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT, handleObjectLoaded);

// For pdf files and those that don't contain geometry do this
ensureModelsWithoutGeometryLoaded(viewer).then(handleObjectLoaded);
```